# Large Amount of cash withdrawals from bank

Tags: united-states, banking, online-banking

I borrowed money from friends to make a cash purchase of 14k on a house. I deposited the funds in small increments.

I was unable to purchase the house because it was sold to the highest bidder.

So I withdrew 14k from my bank to repay the money I borrowed.

I have the contract from from the realty and a copy of the certified check for 1000 that I had to make to put on the offer toward the house.

Am I going to get in trouble for making such a large withdrawal or are there any form that I should fill out.

plz help

Comment: What country are you in? How long before you borrowed the money and are paying back.

Comment: im in the u.s / i borrowed the fund thinking that my offer on the house was going to be accepted, but the offer didn't get accepted so I withdrew the funds to pay back the funds I borrowed from friends

Comment: while there are some regulations on how much money you can withdraw at one time, generally it is considered your money and you can withdraw it, so it is not exactly clear why you are concerned unless there is something else you are not saying

Comment: You may get dinged for"structuring", which is what they call making large transactions in small increments specifically to sidestep the banking regulations intended to prevent money laundering. I would suggest seeking legal advice, but not panic.

Comment: Did you tell the bank when you were prepared to make the down payment, that the money was received as a loan from someone else? The bank needs to know if it's a loan, because they want to be aware of what your other debts are. Lying to your bank about this is setting yourself up for failure, because they may find that the money went in and out, and pursue you for fraud/damages.

Comment: Why did you deposit the funds in small increments rather than all at once? And were those funds all cash? Have you gotten the 1K back from the bank check yet?

Comment: I deposit the cash amount in small increment because the bank was close and the atm doesn't take large deposit, as for the certified check made out to the realty, I deposit it back in my account because I didn't need it anymore since my offer for the house wasn't accepted...

Comment: yes got the money back from the check

Comment: I have promissory notes reverifying the repayments back to borrower...

Answer (score 2):

In the US, the bank is legally required to report any cash transactions over 10k$ to the government. This normally has no consequences, and you will never hear about it. No need to worry about it.

If the amount is very high, or you do it repeatedly, or the government has other (pre-existing) reasons to look at your finances sharply, they might ask you where the money came from and what you did with it, but your explanation is perfectly fine (assuming it is true).

The idea is to catch money-launderers that try to get large illegal cash incomes into the banking system. Classic example is the drug lord who makes a million a month in cash from selling drugs, and needs to get this million into the banks (as you can't buy houses or luxury cars or yachts with cash without getting FBI attention right away).